# create view with two tables that have same columns

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a view with the following results. I can create the first part just fine but the second part is where I am having trouble. When I do the join I am receiving an Error Code: 1052. Column 'customer_id' in field list is ambiguous. Now I know that the in the two tables I have duplicate columns.

My question is how do I write the view to ignore one of the duplicate columns

Create a view named customer_addresses that shows the shipping and billing addresses for each customer. This view should return these columns from the Customers table:

```
customer_id
email_address
last_name
first_name.
```

This view should return these columns from the Addresses table:

```
bill_line1
bill_line2
bill_city
bill_state
bill_zip
ship_line1
ship_line2
ship_city
ship_state
ship_zip
```

The rows in this view should be sorted by the last_name and then first_name columns.

Here is my code.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW customer_addresses
 AS
 SELECT customer_id, email_address, last_name, first_name, addresses.line1
 FROM  customers JOIN addresses
 ORDER BY last_name
```

Comment: share all columns of both table.

Answer (score 0):

I would just identify all the columns like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW customer_addresses
 AS
 SELECT 
    customers.customer_id, 
    customers.email_address, 
    customers.last_name, 
    customers.first_name, 
    addresses.line1
 FROM  customers JOIN addresses
 ORDER BY customers.last_name
```

Because I believe that you have an `customer_id` in the `customers` table and one in the `addresses` table. Right?

If you do not specify the table name and add a column to one of the tables with the same column name as in the view the problem will arise again.